# Different complex structures of a torus.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Consider a complex $\mathbb C/\Lambda$, once we choose a lattice $\Lambda$, then the torus is uniquely determined.

For example, if we choose different lattices: $\Lambda_1=\mathbb Z\oplus i\mathbb Z$, $\Lambda_2=\mathbb Z\oplus 2i\mathbb Z$, and let $T_1=\mathbb C/\Lambda_1$, $T_2=\mathbb C/\Lambda_2$, then do $T_1$ and $T_2$ have different complex structures? I know they have the same diffeomorphism sturcture, but why they have different complex structures? Does there exist an intuitive explanation why they have different complex structures?

Comment: Yes, they are different because both $i, 2i$ are in the [fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_stack_of_elliptic_curves#Fundamental_domain_and_visualization) of the modular group.

Comment: For me the best way to make sense of it is to think about what complex homomorphisms you can construct between different tori. Specifically, a function $f: \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\to\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ must lift to a bi-periodic function $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ (WLOG $\tilde{f}(0)=0$), and $f$ will be holomorphic if and only if $\tilde{f}$ is. But $\tilde{f}^{-1}(\Lambda_2)$ must contain $\Lambda_1$ and be holomorphic, and that constrains not only what homomorphisms there are but especially what isomopshisms exist between $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1$ and $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$

Comment: @Jackson, the answer I'm looking for is somewhat like yours, but why $\tilde{f}^{-1}(\Lambda_2)$ must contain $\Lambda_1$?

Comment: To get a well-defined function $f$, you need $\tilde f(\Lambda_1)\subset\Lambda_2$, no?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, yes, you are right, but for my concrete example, as you said, we may have  $\tilde{f}(1)=a+b(2i)$, $\tilde{f}(i)=c+d(2i)$, $a,b,c,d$ are integers, and form a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$, conversely, we should have another matix $B$ such that $AB=I$, then $A$ should have determinant $\pm1$, then in order to prove $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not isomorphic, we should prove there exist no matrix $A\in SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, such that map $(1,i)$ to $(1,2i)$, but we did not get the contradiction yet, right?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, what if we choose $\Lambda_2=2\mathbb Z\oplus i\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a general procedure used to determine if two tori are biholomorphic to each other. Consider a lattice $\Lambda$ in ${\mathbb C}$ generated by two complex numbers $\alpha, \beta$. I assume that the basis $(\alpha, \beta)$ in ${\mathbb R}^2$ is positively oriented, otherwise, swap $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Consider the ratio $\tau=\beta/\alpha$ (the Teichmuller parameter). Positive orientation implies that $\tau$ is in the upper half-plane $U$, $Im(\tau)>0$. Then, find an element $\gamma\in PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ sending $\tau$ to the modular fundamental domain
$$
F=\{z: - 1/2 \le Re(z)\le 1/2, |z|\ge 1\}. 
$$
If $z=\gamma(\tau)$ is in the interior of $F$, then it is uniquely determined by $\tau$, otherwise, it is unique up to the action of the translation $z\mapsto z\pm 1$ (if $Re(z)=\pm 1/2$) or involution $z\mapsto -1/z$ (if $|z|=1$).

Up to this ambiguity, $z$ uniquely determines the conformal class of the quotient torus ${\mathbb C}/\Lambda$.

In the case of a "rectangular" torus, things are especially simple since $Re(\tau)=0$ and either $\tau\in F$ or $-1/\tau\in F$.

Now, to your specific example (from your comment): $\Lambda_2$ is generated by $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=i$. In this case, $\tau=i/2$, $-1/\tau=2i\in F$. Hence, the torus ${\mathbb C}/\Lambda_2$ is not conformal to the torus ${\mathbb C}/\Lambda_1$.

---

Regarding references: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moduli_stack_of_elliptic_curves#Fundamental_domain_and_visualization) Wikipedia article provides a nice proof of the fact that the *moduli space* of complex one-dimensional tori (aka nonsingular complex elliptic curves) is the quotient of the upper half-plane $U$ by  $\Gamma=PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$. Concretely, this means that if $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2$ are two lattices generated, respectively, by $\alpha_1, \beta_1$ and $\alpha_2, \beta_2$ with $\tau_k=\beta_k/\alpha_k, k=1, 2$, then the tori ${\mathbb C}/\Lambda_k$ are biholomorpbhic if and only if
$$
\Gamma \tau_1 =\Gamma \tau_2. 
$$
The fact that this equality of two orbits is equivalent to
$$
\Gamma \tau_1 \cap F= \Gamma \tau_2 \cap F,
$$
i.e. that $F$ is a *fundamental domain* of $\Gamma$, is explained in many places. One reference is given by the linked Wikipedia article, Chapter VII in

*Serre, Jean-Pierre*, A course in arithmetic, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 7. New York-Heidelberg-Berlin: Springer-Verlag. viii, 115 p. (1973). [ZBL0256.12001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0256.12001).

Another is

*Katok, Svetlana*, Fuchsian groups, Chicago Lectures in Mathematics. Chicago: The University of Chicago Press,. x, 175 p. (1992). [ZBL0753.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0753.30001).

Or, freely available Pete Clark's lecture notes on Shimura curves [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/expositions2012.html).

Lastly, a true story: A math professor is flying in an airplane, reading Serre's book "A course in arithmetic." His next-seat neighbor notices the title and approvingly says "**Very good, it is never too late to learn!**"

Comment: Is there any good reference stating the proof process of the equivalent class of complex structure is decided by $H/PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$, where $H$ is the upper half complex plane?

Comment: @Tom: See the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think with your answer and the comments of Ted and Jackson, everything is clear to me.

Comment: @Tom: Good. In general, you should not rush with accepting an answer if something is still unclear.

Comment: Your answer solves large part of the problem, the rest part seemed being within my reach, and indeed after a little more effort, I think I can persuade myself that I have understood it totally. But I think your suggestion is quite reasonable and next time I will accept the answer untill I'm sure nothing is left unclear.